# How are Toffoli and a basis-changing single-qubit gate universal?

Tags: quantum-circuit, universal-gates

The Toffoli and Hadamard gates are universal for quantum computing: you can approximate any unitary up to arbitrary precision with a circuit built from these two gates. This is proved for example by [Aharonov](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301040), based on work by [Shi](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205115). More precisely, Shi proves that instead of Hadamard, it suffices to take any single-qubit gate whose 2-by-2 unitary matrix has real entries and that does not preserve the computational basis (Theorem 1.1).

```
Why is it important that the entries are real? 
Is Toffoli together with a complex single-qubit basis-changing gate universal?
```

He says this theorem "follows immediately" from (Theorem 3.2) Toffoli and Hadamard forming a universal gate set.

```
How does this follow?
```

I know there are other, later, approaches to similar results, for example by [Brylinski and Brylinski](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108062), with proofs that I do understand, but would just like to understand the above two issues.